# Probability / Mean of two randomly drawn sequences?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say I have a real valued random variable $X$ distributed according to a continuous *non normal* cdf $G(x)$ with mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$ and pdf $g(x)$. Furthermore I have a set of natural number $[k]$ where $\{k \in \mathbb{N} : 0 < k < 30\}$. Now I go on as follows:

1. From $[k]$ I randomly sample one number $K$
2. From $X$, I sample my first random sequence of size $K$: $S_1=\{x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, ..., x_{1,K}\}$ with sample mean $\bar{S_1}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K x_{1,k}$.
3. From $X$, I sample my second random sequence of size $K$: $S_2=\{x_{2,1}, x_{2,2}, ..., x_{2,K}\}$ with sample mean $\bar{S_2}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K x_{2,k}$

What is now the probability that $\bar{S_2} < \bar{S_1}$?

Comment: Both sample mean is a continuous random variable, and has the identical distribution. The probability that two continuous random variables equal is $0$, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take my answer with a grain of salt, but wouldn't it be $ \frac{1}{2} $? I assume that the sampling is an independent event in your case. In that case, since $ \overline{S}_1 $ and $ \overline{S}_2 $ are i.i.d., the chance that $ P(\overline{S}_2 < \overline{S}_1) = P(\overline{S}_2 > \overline{S}_1) = P(\overline{S}_2 \geq \overline{S}_2) $, where the last equation holds since $ \overline{S}_1, \overline{S}_2 $ are continuously distributed (at least I assume you meant that with "real valued random variable X"). Since $ 1 = P(\overline{S}_2 < \overline{S}_1) + P(\overline{S}_2 \geq \overline{S}_2) $, it follows in total that $ P(\overline{S}_2 < \overline{S}_1) = P(\overline{S}_2 \geq \overline{S}_2) = P(\overline{S}_2 > \overline{S}_2) = 0.5 $

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I noticed I asked the wrong question.. I reposted it, maybe you can help me on that one, too?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362173/probability-two-random-variables-mean-of-two-randomly-drawn-sequences

Comment: Can't promise that, but if I end up procrastinating anyway, I might try a take at it! May I just know if it's part of your homework that you are trying to get solved? If so, it would be nice if you could also show that you have at least attempted to solve it on your own :).